# How to show Pop-ups in Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk, popupwindow, corona-storyboard

I am trying to show a pop-up window on a button click event using storyboard.showOverlay(), which is just a scene over another scene. Is there any function through which I can show a proper pop-up window?

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use storyboard to achieve this 
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/hideOverlay.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am using storyboard.showOverlay and storyboard.hideOverlay for this purpose. I am getting problem in scene changing on overlay. I have a pause button which overlays 3 buttons on touch which are, Back to Menu, Resume and Restart, respectively. On "Back to Menu" button event I am using storyboard.hideOverlay and storyboard.gotoScene which should be able to redirect me to Menu class. But it is not working and giving error. Is there any way to resolve this error?

Comment: You can add one popUp at a time once it is hidden from screen then other one can be added, please check does the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

WE can show a popup screen by using storyboard.showOverlay(). 
**Step 1:**
here is the code of block for it. If we set "isModal = true" then it'll restrict user to perform any activity on back window.

```
local options =
{
    effect = "fade",
    time = 100,
    params =
        {
            sample_var = "anything parameter to send",
            theme = "another parameter to send",
            data = "another parameter to send"
        },
    isModal = true
}

storyboard.showOverlay( "pause", options )
```

**Step 2:** To hide the overlay again:

```
     local options ={
    effect = "fade",
    time = 100,
    isModal = false,
}storyboard.hideOverlay( "pause", options )
```

**WE can also implement delegate methods of overlay:**

-- the following event is dispatched once the overlay is in place

```
    function scene:overlayBegan( event )

   -- print( "Showing overlay: " .. event.sceneName )
end
scene:addEventListener( "overlayBegan" )
```

-- the following event is dispatched once overlay is removed

```
    function scene:overlayEnded( event )

   -- print( "Overlay removed: " .. event.sceneName )
end
scene:addEventListener( "overlayEnded" )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to use overlays for this purpose. As overlays calls a class. I just want to know if there is any method which shows pop-ups. For example to show buttons we import widget class and show buttons. Same as like if there any class or method except overlays?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do the popup:  native.newTextBox, native.showAlert, your own display group with graphics, display text, a storyboard scene if you're using storyboard as an Overlay.  There are tons of ways to do this.

But the real question you probably have is how to make it only display once.  The way I do this is I have a settings file where I save things like musicOn, soundOn, etc.  When I start up, I read this file.  If it does not exist, I create it with my initial settings.  But this also tells me that if I don't have this file, it's my first time running the app and I can show my initial help screen in the manner of my choosing.